# Does BigQuery support nested CASE statements?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a requirement which looks something like:

```
If X <0.01 then Y=1, Z=2
If X>=0.01 then
  If <another_expression> then Y=3, Z=4
  If <another_expression> then Y=5, Z=6
```

and so on, where 'Y' and 'Z' are column aliases.

I had a look at using the CASE statement, but it doesn't seem to support **nested** CASE statements.

Am I missing something obvious? Or is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this? just quick guess.

```
SELECT
  X,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(result, r'(\d+),') AS Y,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(result, r',(\d+)') AS Z
FROM (
  SELECT 
  X,
  CASE WHEN X <0.01 THEN '1,2'
  WHEN X >= 0.01 THEN (
    CASE WHEN X < 0.1 THEN '3,4'
    WHEN X >= 0.1 THEN '5,6' END
  ) END AS result
  FROM (SELECT 0.2 AS X)
)
```